# Eclipse WTP: Glassfish does not include WEB-INF/lib in classpath

Tags: eclipse, glassfish, eclipse-wtp

I started a new dynamic web project in eclipse helios. I integrated glassfish into eclipse and it works fine so far. Except one thing:
I place my libraries (jdbc, log4j etc.) in WEB-INF/lib. Eclipse deploys that files correctly to glassfish, but glassfish does not include that directory in its classpath, so my app won't run (because it can't find the jars).

When I edit the server's "launch configuration" in eclipse, I can manually add the libs under "Classpath", but that don't change a thing.

Only when I manully copy the jars to glassfish's lib/ext folder, the libs are included.

When I used tomcat as a server it works, the libs are in tomcat's classpath. But I want to use glassfish without copying the libs manually.

Any idea?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My servlet did not find the jdbc driver, so I thought it was a lib missing. Calling “ClassForName“ solved the problem. This seems strange to me, as this is not needed when used in the SE context.
So eclipse is correctly deploying the libs, just a little extra code is needed.

Comment: You should accept this answer to indicate that your problem is solved.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure how do you add the libs in your project.
Try to show the project  properties tab, select the Deployment Assembly node section, and click the add button. Select archives from file system or project (if your lib i also an Eclipse j2se project).
This should work.
Hoping you use the latest Eclipse 3.6 SR1 and the latest glassfish plugin from the update Center: http://download.java.net/glassfish/eclipse/helios

Comment: worked like a dream, thanks for the proper and elegant response!